# I cannot configure jest properly to import modules (setupFilesAfterEnv)

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I am using `@angular-builders/jest` in order to replace karma by jest when testing angular projects.
There are 2 libraries that I like to get extra matchers for jest: `jest-extended` and `@testing-library/jest-dom`.

I cannot find a way to import automatically the matchers so that I don't have to import them in each spec file.

**minimal example to reproduce the problem with `jest-extended`**

First, create an angular project and install jest dependencies

```sh
ng new --defaults my-project
cd my-project
yarn add -D jest @types/jest @angular-builders/jest jest-extended
```

Then edit `angular.json` to replace builder

```
...
"test": {
    "builder": "@angular-builders/jest:run"
},
```

So far, I can run and pass the tests using jest with command

```sh
ng test
```

Now I add a test using one of the jest-extended matchers. In `app.component.spec.ts`:

```
...
  it('should work with jest-extended matchers', () => {
    expect([1, 1, 1]).toBeArrayOfSize(3);
  });
```

**Attempt #1**

create `jest.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    'jest-extended',
  ],
};
```

Does not work, I get error `TS2339: Property 'toBeArrayOfSize' does not exist on type 'ArrayLikeMatchers<number>'`

**Attempt #2**

use an intermediate setup file; create `jest.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    'my-jest-setup.ts',
  ],
};
```

with `my-jest-setup.ts`

```
import 'jest-extended'
```

Works! Test passes... BUT as soon as I change something in my spec file

```
...
  it('should work with jest-extended matchers', () => {
    expect([1, 1, 1]).toBeArrayOfSize(3);
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

and run the test again, I get the same error as in attempt #1. I suspect a cache issue

**Workaround**

Use attempt #2 and clear jest cache before each run with

```
ng test --clearCache && ng test
```

I don't like this solution because the cache is intended to speed up things and clearing the cache each time has a sensitive impact when there are many spec files. Moreover, I don't think it is possible to clear cache when using jest in watch mode

Sorry, this was a bit long, thanks if you read it to the end

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found what I believe the right solution. Starting from *minimal example to reproduce the problem with jest-extended*,

1. create `jest.config.js` file (Attempt 1 was finally a good start)

```js
module.exports = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    'jest-extended',
  ],
};
```

2. edit `tsconfig.spec.json` and replace `"types": ["jasmine", "node"]` by `"types": ["jest", "node", "jest-extended"]`

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": ["jest", "node", "jest-extended"] // <==== what was missing
  },
  "files": ["src/test.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

and voilà. This will actually includes `jest` and `jest-extended` declaration files in compilation. I now get all the benefits of TypeScript type checkings and the speed improvements of the cache (except for first run, obviously).

I hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

I think I found a solution. The trick is to simply enable a `ts-jest` option in `jest.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['jest-extended'],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      isolatedModules: true,
    },
  },
};
```

I have to admit that I don't understand the goal of this option, hence, any enlightenment will be highly appreciated.

As a bonus, test execution is way faster.

No apparent drawback so far, but I let you know if strange things happen.

I hope this helps

Edit: the actual drawback is that we loose type checking when ts-jest compiles for running the tests. The goal of the `isolatedModules` option is explained in [ts-jest documentation](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/user/config/isolatedModules)

Comment: `isolatedModules` will, as described in the [docs](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/user/config/isolatedModules), basically just blindly create JavaScript without checking any TypeScript when running test. This means you could even make this pass: `const someNumber: number = "5";` with isolatedModules on.

This will increase testing speed, but make your tests not fail, when e. g. some imported types change.

Comment: @wtho yeah, I am aware of losing type checking, as already said in this answer. For me, it is an acceptable trade-off for now since I still have typescript errors highlighted by vs code. But you are right, tests won't break if types change, and I am still interested in a way to have full type checking without having to clear cache between each test execution