# unexpected uncovered branch in jest coverage

Tags: angular, jestjs, code-coverage, jest-preset-angular

I am testing an angular project with jest (using `jest-preset-angular`).

When collecting coverage, I get an uncovered branch and I don't understand why. I can reproduce the problem with 3 files.

`some-dependency.ts`

```js
export class SomeDependency {}
```

`some-service.ts`

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SomeDependency } from './some-dependency';

@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
    constructor(private dependency: SomeDependency) {
        console.log('service created');
    }
}
```

`some-service.spec`

```js
import { SomeService } from './some-service';

describe('DerivedClass', () => {
    it('should create', () => {
        expect(new SomeService(null)).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

by running `yarn jest --coverage some-service`, I get following coverage:

```
--------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File                |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
--------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files           |      100 |       75 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 some-dependency.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 some-service.ts    |      100 |       75 |      100 |      100 |                 6 |
--------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

in the HTML report, I get too little information on what is uncovered.

[image]

I noticed that removing `@Injectable` decorator makes the coverage back to 100%

Does someone have an explanation? Is there a way to get my 100% coverage while keeping `@Injectable` decorator?

**Edit:** I have added a console.log to prove the constructor is properly invoked. The yellow highlight is given by Istambul report and helps to see the uncovered branch. But there is no branch to me here since there is no condition.

Comment: Which version of `jest-preset-angular` and `ts-jest` are you using?

Comment: @wtho I think it was `jest-preset-angular@7.1.1` and `ts-jest@24.0.0`

Answer (score 5):

By comparing with the brand new project created by @markusdresch where coverage is 100% indeed, I finally found that one `ts-jest` option set in `jest.config.js` causes side effect on code coverage.

```js
{
    // ...
    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            // ...
            isolatedModules: true,
        },
    },
}
```

`isolatedModules` set to true causes the uncovered branch described in the original question. By setting it to false or removing it, coverage is back to 100%.

I wish I could use `isolatedModules = true` and still have a 100% coverage, but I guess this should be a brand new question.

Comment: FYI, the reason I want to use `isolatedModules` is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57442151/i-cannot-configure-jest-properly-to-import-modules-setupfilesafterenv)

Comment: Hi @sergio-mazzoleni , have you had any chance to make isolatedModules = true work with 100% coverage? Unfortunately, disabling it in my case generates a huge memory heap because of the size of the project and I don't need type-hinting in tests

Comment: @Joseph no, sorry, I gave up because I was using `isolatedModules: true` as a workaround for another problem, but I finally fixed the "root" issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59041659/3572918)

Comment: I've solved by disabling decorators in my tsconfig.test.json and mocking them. Now I can keep `isolatedModules: true`. I don't need type-hinting in jest (the build process is enough already) and the performance without it are outstanding.

Answer (score 1):

I created a brand new Angular app, added jest-preset-angular and the tests you mention, and it's 100% code coverage.

Check out https://github.com/markusdresch/angular-jest-example

```
---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File                 |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files            |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 app                 |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  app.component.html |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  app.component.ts   |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 models              |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  some-dependency.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 services            |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  some.service.ts    |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I already tried what you propose and it has no effect on code coverage, still at 75% when using TestBed

Comment: what if you create a component that consumes the service and test the component?

Comment: Alas, it makes no difference

Comment: what does your component.spec look like? does it have a `ConfigureFn`? i get 100% coverage.

Comment: i added the full procedure

Comment: I appreciate the time and efforts you put in this. However... 1) I still don't get 100% coverage with your proposal; 2) it seems to be a lot of code for a simple branch not covered 3) I don't even understand what is not covered, I mean the service constructor is executed since an instance is properly created 4) create a component to test a service seems odd to me. There should be an easier way :-)

Comment: I edited my question. I just like to understand what branch is uncovered...

Comment: added example. 100% coverage.

Comment: By comparing your project with mine, I finally discovered that the `ts-jest` option `isolatedModules: true` I use in `my jest.config.js` seems to be the culprit. By removing it, coverage is 100%. I owe you one :-)